# Want to move files of type .*** to root. Then repeat on next folder

Tags: windows, batch-processing

Here is what I have:

```
Root Folder
 -Folder A
   -many nested subfolders containing .pdf files and .txt files
 -Folder B
   -many nested subfolders containing .pdf files and .txt files
 -Folder C
   -many nested subfolders containing .pdf files and .txt files
```

I would like a script that from the root folder will grab all of the pdf and txt files within Folder A and put them at the root of Folder A, then do Folder B, then Folder C and so on.

I've found similar scripts out there but since I don't know how to do this I don't really know how to modify the scripts.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on a dummy set of folder/files: it doesn't handle filename collisions

```
@echo off
cd /d "d:\folder"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  pushd "%%a"
    for /r %%b in (*.pdf *.txt) do echo "%%b" & move "%%b" . >nul 
  popd
)
echo done
pause
```

Comment: No luck.  I modified it to include a different file extension.    No errors, just doesn't move anything.    `@echo off`  
`cd /d "C:\Users\username\Desktop\PDFs"`  
`for /d %%a in (*) do (`  
    `for /r "%%a" %%b in (*.pdf *.bsd *.bsdl) do move "%%b" "%%a"`  
`)`

Comment: There have to be folders underneath `"C:\Users\username\Desktop\PDFs"` with the files inside them.  Say `"C:\Users\username\Desktop\PDFs\my files\one.pdf"`

Comment: That's what I have.  Maybe I'm executing it wrong?  I just put it in a text file and called it a .bat and then doubleclicked the file.

Comment: Place `pause` as the last line.  See if there is an error message.

Comment: "Press any key to continue..."  I wish I knew some of this so I could modify it and play around but all the %%a and %%b's, some with quotes and some without really throw me off.

Comment: I found this, seems like it would be needed but then again, I have no idea what I'm doing.  `/s: makes it recursively go through each of the subdirectories`

Comment: It needed some tinkering.  Test it now